# Converse of the Cauchy Triangle Theorem (Complex Analysis)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to find a counter-example to the converse of the Cauchy triangle theorem in complex analysis:

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain. If $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous such that $\int_{\Gamma}fdz=0$ $\forall$ triangles $\Gamma \subset D$, then $f$ has an anti-derivative.

I know that this statement is true if $D$ is  a star domain, but I'm not sure what a counter example might be if $D$ is an arbitrary domain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no counterexample, see [morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)

Comment: Thank you again!